# How to determine if Python DB-API connection object is of a certain DBMS (e.g., PostgreSQL, MySQL)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, postgresql, python-db-api

Let the `driver` be a DB-API driver (e.g., `psycopg2`, `pymysql`) and you can get the connection object via `connnection = driver.connect(...)`. How do I check what kind of DBMS the connection object is connected to: (1) At best the DBMS name or (2) the module name.

**Use Case:**

I need to make special queries that are of different SQL syntax (e.g., `COPY` clause for PostgreSQL vs using bulk `INSERT` for MySQL).

Comment: at the time you a connection you know the type, and can select the querys

Comment: The issue with that is when you pass the connection object to another function. You'd then need to pass another arg to describe the DBMS name which is not preferable. An attribute that is attached to the connection would be best.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should already know the DB-API to use and what operations to run. Please post example code for your use case to illustrate your real issue.

Comment: Not really, @nbk did really well both in understanding this problem and then provided a solution that satisfies the use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like?:

```
type(con)                                                                                                                                                                  
psycopg2.extensions.connection

type(con)                                                                                                                                                                  
sqlite3.Connection
```

Or shorter yet:

```
con.__class__                                                                                                                                                             
psycopg2.extensions.connection

con.__class__                                                                                                                                                             
sqlite3.Connection
```

Comment: Answers require some exlpantation

Comment: The code is the explanation. No point in adding verbiage that does no more then repeat what the code shows.

Comment: no answer needs to explain whar the code does, as your first example check the type of the connection variabe that can be checked

Comment: Be useful, write your own answer instead of critiquing an answer the questioner already understands.

Comment: It's a good solution to get the module name. Preferably, I'm looking to get the DBMS name without the need to map module/class/type to DBMS string.

Comment: Not sure you can get that from connection. I would say the solution would be to set a variable to the DBMS name when you create the connection and use that.

Comment: It's a limitation of DB-API V2 it seems. If they required that the URI to be stored as an attribute or or add the DBMS on dsn attribute this problem would be easily solved.